# Low beam not working in Pulsar 150 AS

Tags: motorcycle, headlight, pulsar

few days ago suddenly my bike low beam stop working and its always showing high beam.I already change the indicators panel but issue is same. Whenever I switch on the lights, its gone on high beam and even I am not able to us dipper which creates issue on the night time.please help asap

Comment: The low beam filament on your build might have blown out, Replace the bulb.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a case of buld malfunction, but since you say that you're not able to use dipper too I would recomment checking output at the bulb holder. and then make a decision accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your lowbeam bulb is fused.have it checked,if it's fine then the problem will be with the dipper switch and you will have to get it changed.